# Transpose/Pivot, Match, & Index? Not sure how to handle this scenario

Tags: google-sheets

I've been messing around with this for quite some time, but I can't figure out how to get the data to "pivot" & match the way I intend it to.. I've tried about 100 different scenarios, but Google Sheets isn't quite my forte.

Basically I have a bunch of raw input data, all of the input data has static point values (but there are 1000's of potential "items" associated with each input value) There could be upwards of a hundred "people" that have a static list of items & associated values.

The desired outcome is basically a list of all the items(which are hard coded & grouped by class already in a second spreadsheet).. With all potential "persons" & the value they assigned the items on the first spreadsheet from highest to lowest.

[RAW DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYkIE.png)

[DESIRED OUTCOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa7nK.png)

Example below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyynGtXublw_0nOF7aulXaX8bA5KmPlGJ76mRcJvIog/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So do you basically want to take this data from one sheet and order it accordingly in another sheet (and if new data is added in the first sheet to get ordered on the second one)? Do you exclusively want to use Google Sheets formulas or are you also open to an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) solution?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I'm open to any potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) functionalities. To access the script editor, on the Sheets menu bar go to **Tools -> Script editor** and paste the following code. Before you would need to create a "Solution" sheet with the hard coded information you provided in the example sheet (i.e the item number column). The rest will be added accordingly dynamically.

The following piece of code has self explanatory comments:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get origin Sheet where we have our unordered data
  var originSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw Data');
  // Get sheet where we will order the data
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Solution');
  
  // Get the range on the unordered data sheet where the items will be placed
  var values = originSheet.getRange('B2:E6').getValues();
  // Get the values (names) of the items in the ordered data sheet (for instance #item1)
  var items = destinationSheet.getRange('A3:A8').getValues().flat();
  
  // Iterate over all the columns first and then rows of the range of unordered data
  // where we have all of our items. 
  for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){ // columns
    for(j=0;j<values[i].length;j++){ // rows
      
  // Iterate over all the possible items in our ordered data, from item1 to item5
      for(k=0;k<items.length;k++){
        
/* If the value of the unordered data cell we are checking matches the value
 of the item name then we know that the information of that unordered value
 belongs to that item. For example, in the first case if the first cell in row 2 and col 2
of the underered data matches item1 (which does) then we know we must provide the information
to that ordered item value */
        
        if(values[i][j]==items[k]){
          
          // This is for checking the last column with a value to avoid writing over blank cells
          var lastCol=0;
          // Iterate over 10 columns
          for(y=0;y<10;y++){
          // If the column in the row of item1 is empty, then we must write the information there
            if(destinationSheet.getRange(k+3,y+2).getValue()==""){
              lastCol=y+2;
              break;
            }
          }
          // Now that we know where we must write the info, with the information of the row and column values
          // of the cell we can get their corresponding elements and make a string where we get them together to 
          // finally set the right cell in the destination sheet
          destinationSheet.getRange(k+3,lastCol).setValue(originSheet.getRange(i+2,1).getValue()+ ' - '+originSheet.getRange(1, j+2).getValue());
          
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```